# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '/Users/User/Downloads/TrafficSigns\\TrafficSigns/Training'

Tags: tensorflow

[path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPvGc.png)
[ROOT_PATH = "C:/Users/User/Downloads/TrafficSigns"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROjlk.png)
[I am having problem in uploading data but can't figure out the problem. the code is given in the attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fERf1.png)

Comment: one of your / is in the wrong direction

Comment: sorry, i didn't get your answer

Answer (score 0):

You are running on Windows. There is no such thing as the '/' root path on Windows.

Provide the correct path to the TrafficSigns directory. It is porbably "C:/Users/User/...". If forward slashes are not allowed, just replace them with double backslashes.

Comment: ROOT_PATH = "C:/Users/User/Downloads/TrafficSigns"
changing the path to this gives the same error
is anywhere else needed to be changed?

Comment: I have added screen shots for you to check

Comment: You have TrafficSigns twice. remove it from either the root path what you append to it.